# Android - how to animate color change along a path

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas

i have created a curved path like this:

```
 pathCurve.moveTo(0f, 0f)

        pathCurve.cubicTo(0f,300f,500f, 300f, 500f,300f);
```

and it looks like this:

https://media1.tenor.com/images/de7ca7ff1c54e69ca2f77d8bc3cb8ef6/tenor.gif?itemid=5424985

I thought since i have a path i could use a path interprelator. then i saw ObjectAnimator has it build in so i try:

```
val path = Path().apply {
        cubicTo(0f,300f,500f, 300f, 500f,300f);
    }
    val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.X, View.Y, path).apply {
        duration = 2000
        start()
    }
```

but how do change the color. it seems there are 2 animations occuring. one makes it dark, then the second reverses it back to lite  color. so what i have is not even enough.

then i thought i could animate the background color but i cant get this to compile:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this,"backgroundColor", Color.Gray,Color.BLUE,path).apply {
            duration = 2000
            start()
        }
```

seems its not working with path.  How can i achieve this effect given i already have a curved path created ?

UPDATE : here is what i have tried now:

```
fun backgroundColor(vararg colors: Int) {
        val objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pathCurve, "backgroundColor", *colors)
        objectAnimator.setEvaluator(ArgbEvaluator())
        objectAnimator.start()
    }
```

and i call it like this:

```
backgroundColor(Color.RED)
```

i am also getting this lint warning:

[image]
but nothing happens.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.animation.ObjectAnimator/setEvaluator?snippet=5ce698a537d9ff0004be43b6).

Comment: hey thanks for writing. i still dont know how to use that with a path, i tried this:  val objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt( "backgroundColor", *colors,myPath)
        objectAnimator.setEvaluator(ArgbEvaluator()) but it does not compile

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i figured out a way to do this ...the algorithm is to use measuredPath and an object animator with two animations.

Comment: ObjectAnimator with two animations? Explain please

Comment: animations.playSequentially(animator(0L, false), animator(400L, true)) as a example